# Python: why is string not appending to every element in the list?

Tags: python, string, list, append, output

```
files = "a.txtb.txt"

if files.find( ".txt" ) != -1:
    files = files.split( ".txt" )
    files.remove( "" )
    [ file + ".txt" for file in files ]
    print( files )
```

I'm new to python. The output I want is the list files = [a.txt, b.txt] in the end, but for testing reasons I have to do all that stuff in the front first. I don't understand why the string cannot be appended to all the elements in my list.

Comment: Why not just `split()` on `', '`?

Comment: And by "cannot be appended" do you mean "was appended but then thrown away because the result wasn't reassigned to `files`"?

Comment: Or better yet, `re.split` can split for a multitude of characters.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I meant there are no "," in the beginning, oops.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 thank you! I forgot to reassign it. I assumed it worked just like remove() does where I wouldn't have to reassign it.

Comment: The ideal solution would be to avoid ever mashing all your filenames together into one string with no delimiter, or else you end up having to solve [problem Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 This can be easily solved with regex.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: So what? This can also be easily solved without regex. In fact, the OP was very close to solving it himself. And, of course, it wouldn't _have_ to be solved in the first place if he didn't do whatever caused his data to be like this.

Comment: The fastest code is the code that doesn't need to run.

Comment: Yeah, I guess he just forgot to reassign the comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the list back to `files`. As it stands it just throws the list with the appended values away.

e.g.

```
files = [ file + ".txt" for file in files ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a non-greedy regular expression to find the contained text files:

```
files = re.findall(r'\w+?\.txt', file_string)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do the following to obtain the desired result:

```
files = "a.txt, b.txt"
results = files.split( ',' )
```

After this, **results** will contain the desired result in the form of a list.